# Зеркала rfremix (альтернатива) для mirror.yandex.ru

Tags: linux, fedora, dnf

На днях сменил провайдера, и обнаружил, что блокирован mirror.yandex.* (Я с Украины) Из-за этого не могу устанавливать программы на линуксе. Какие есть способы решения проблемы? Зеркала, альтернативные сервера?

Почти вся конфигурация нацелена на сервера Яндекса (за малым исключением)

Часть грузится с серверов Федоры, не могу добраться до следующих

```
Russian Fedora for Fedora 29 - Branding - Updates                                                                                  0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:31    
Russian Fedora for Fedora 29 - Branding                                                                                            0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:31    
Russian Fedora for Fedora 29 - Fixes - Updates                                                                                     0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:31    
Russian Fedora for Fedora 29 - Fixes                                                                                               0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:31    
Russian Fedora for Fedora 29 - Free - Updates                                                                                      0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:31    
Russian Fedora for Fedora 29 - Free                                                                                                0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:31    
Russian Fedora for Fedora 29 - Nonfree - Updates                                                                                   0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:31    
Russian Fedora for Fedora 29 - Nonfree
```

Comment: https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/

Comment: @andreymal дело в том, что это зеркала для оригинальной федоры, а мне нужно для rfremix.

Comment: Очень зря вы не указали это сразу прямо в тексте вопроса

Comment: Для rfremix зеркал может и не быть. Лучше спросите у сообщества rfremix, а не здесь

Comment: @andreymal только что сам "докопался" почему не все устанавливается. Со старым провайдером такого не было.

Comment: Через `Tor` пробовал?

Comment: @donRumata, я даже не знаю что это.

Comment: Поднимаешь `tor` на своей машине, пускаешь через него `dnf`. Должно работать. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor.